# troubles savinga value with AsyncStorage

Tags: reactjs, react-native

hit I am developing a form app in reactnative using axios, but i need to pass a value from an api to another ones,
 the value is `response.data.solicitude_id` when i consol log it it prints the value i need like 10 or 39? this is my code

```
const guardar = dispatch => async ({ vName, vSecondName, vLastName, vSecondLastName, vCellphone, vBirthDate, vRFC, vGender, vEmail, vCreationUser }) => {
    try {
        const id = await AsyncStorage.getItem('id');
        const vCreationUser = id;
        const response = await ForceApi.post('/ValidationPersonalInfoController.php', { vName, vSecondName, vLastName, vSecondLastName, vCellphone, vBirthDate, vRFC, vGender, vEmail, vCreationUser });
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('SolicitudeId', response.data.solicitude_id);
        dispatch({ type: 'guardar', payload: response.data.id, });console.log(response.data);
        console.log(response.data.solicitude_id);
        navigate('SolDatosDomicilio');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        dispatch({
        type: 'add_error',
        payload: 'Error de Conexion'
        });
    }
};
```

the error that shows the console log says "java.lang.Double cannot be cast ti java.lang.String"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AsyncStorage only stores string data** and you are I guess trying to save double data to async storage in

`await AsyncStorage.setItem('SolicitudeId', response.data.solicitude_id);`

You want to change it to:

`await AsyncStorage.setItem('SolicitudeId', response.data.solicitude_id+"");`

*Hope this helps. Cheers!*

Comment: oh, my bad im trying to save an int

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the value  `response.data.solicitude_id`to a string

There are 4 options to do this

- `"" + response.data.solicitude_id`
- `String(response.data.solicitude_id)`
- `response.data.solicitude_id.toString`
- 

```
let id = response.data.solicitude_id;
await AsyncStorage.setItem('SolicitudeId',`${id}`);
```